# Is there a VS Code keyboard shortcut for opening the next match in a multiple file search?

Tags: visual-studio-code

So I run a multiple search in files. I get a list of results. I open one and do my thing on it, then close it. Now I want to open the next file from the list of matches. Can I do it with a shortcut, without using the mouse? Couldn't find a keyboard shortcut for that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `search.action.focusNextSearchResult` and `search.action.focusPreviousSearchResult` to navigate through the search results.

On Windows their default keybindings are <kbd>F4</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>.